# Помогите решить задачу на python (ограничение входной информации)

Tags: python

Прошу помочь в решении задачи:
у меня есть входная информация в виде одной строки, в которой содержится две подстроки, разделенные пробелом. Мне нужно чтобы эта информация была только нижнего регистра и содержала только русский алфавит.
Перевод в  ниж.регистр я нашла решение строковой функцией lower(но возможно неверно)

```
word1 = word1.lower() 
word2 = word2.lower()
#....
string = input().split()
print(check(string[0], string[1])
```

Про использования алфавита нашла только ^[а-яё]*$, но не пойму как это использовать.
**Подскажите пожалуйста как можно сделать или где можно почитать, т.к. почему-то не могу найти информацию.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `lower` может подойти для перевода слова в нижний регистр. Но если нужна просто проверка строки на нижний регистр, то будет вполне достаточно регулярного выражения.

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'^[а-яё]*$')
def check(input_str):
    return pattern.match(input_str)
```

В этом примере регулярное выражение проверяет, находится ли строка в нижнем регистре и содержит ли только кириллицу. Если нам регистр неважен, то в параметры метода `re.compile` добавляется флаг `re.I` или `re.IGNORECASE`.

Comment: спасибо! А не используя модуль re, как-то можно сделать?

Comment: Если только реализовать метод, который проверяет каждый символ на караллицу. Тогда для этого придётся импортировать (или самому перечислить) алфавит в нижнем регистре...

Comment: большое спасибо!